# macvim highlights everything opening a file

Tags: macvim

When I open a file with MacVim, It highlights everything in red.

I am not sure how to get rid of this permanently. How can I do this in *.vimrc*?

Comment: Do you have a strange colorscheme? Do you have toyed with autocommands?

Answer (score 0):

set encoding=utf-8
let mapleader = ','
colorscheme koehler
""colorscheme: 
  " blue, darkblue, default, delek, desert, elflord
  " evening, koehler, morning, purphy, pablo
  " peachpuff, ron, shine, slate, solarized, torte, zellner
"set cmdheight=1
"set showmatch
set gfn=Menlo:h14
"=========================================================================
syntax on
set showmode
set nocompatible    " use vim defaults
set number          " show line numbers
set ignorecase      " ignore case when searching 
set title           " show title in console title bar
set ruler           " show the cursor position all the time
set scrolloff=0     " keep 3 lines when scrolling
set ls=2            " allways show status line, or set laststatus=2
set showcmd         " display incomplete commands
set expandtab       " expand tab to spaces
set tabstop=4       " numbers of spaces of tab character
set shiftwidth=4    " numbers of spaces to (auto) indent
set autoindent      " always set autoindenting on
set smartindent     " smart indent
"set cindent         " cindent
set hlsearch        " highlight searches
set incsearch       " do incremental searching
"set visualbell t_vb=    " turn off error beep/flash
"set novisualbell    " turn off visual bell
"set ttyfast         " smoother changes
"set ttyscroll=0     " turn off scrolling, didn't work well with PuTTY
"set modeline        " last lines in document sets vim mode
"set modelines=3     " number lines checked for modelines
"set shortmess=atI   " Abbreviate messages
"set nostartofline   " don't jump to first character when paging
set whichwrap=b,s,h,l,<,>,[,]   " move freely between files
"set nowrap          " don't wrap lines
"set nobackup        " do not keep a backup file
"set viminfo='20,<50,s10,h
"Recursively set the path of the project.
set path=$PWD/**
set spellfile=~/.vim/spell/mySpellFile.en.utf-8.add

" Keyboard mappings
"inoremap  
nnoremap  :buffers:buffer
"nnoremap  :!pdflatex %
nnoremap  :!./cmp %
nnoremap  :setlocal spell spelllang=en_us
nnoremap  :set nospell
nnoremap  .
nnoremap  j
nnoremap  h
nnoremap  k
nnoremap  l
"Vimdiff settings
"nnoremap u :diffupdate
nnoremap du :diffupdate
"nnoremap g :diffget
"nnoremap p :diffput
"remove tailing whitespace
nnoremap W :%s/\s+$//
nnoremap < :winc <
nnoremap > :winc >
"copy full file name to clipboard
nnoremap cp :let @*= expand("%:p")
"cut
vnoremap  :!pbcopy
"copy
vnoremap  :w !pbcopy
"paste in visual mode
vnoremap  :!pbpaste
"paste in normal mode
nnoremap  :r !pbpaste
nnoremap  :noh

filetype on
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.mrs set filetype=c  " set .mrs file to c highlight
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.th set filetype=c
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.izf set filetype=c
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.dat set filetype=c
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.org set filetype=c
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.bak set filetype=c
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.inp set filetype=c

" have Vim jump to the last position when reopening a file
if has("autocmd")
 au BufReadPost * if line("'\"") > 0 && line("'\"") <= line("$")
 \| exe "normal! g'\"" | endif
endif

Comment: That is my vimrc file, sorry all lines are connected!

Comment: I did not have this problem before, it is happening recently!

Comment: colorscheme koehler